# Create 2 moving points along circle MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I want to have 2 moving points along a circle in MATLAB. I have the following script:

```
xCenter = 5;
yCenter = 5;
theta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi;
radius = 8;
x = radius * cos(theta) + xCenter;
y = radius * sin(theta) + yCenter;

figure
plot(x,y);
hold on; % hold on so that the figure is not cleared
hLine = line('XData',x(1), 'YData',y(1), 'Color','r', ...  
    'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',6, 'LineWidth',2);  
hLine2 = line('XData',x(1), 'YData',y(1), 'Color','g', ...  
    'Marker','o', 'MarkerSize',6, 'LineWidth',2); 


for i=1:length(x)
 set(hLine,'xdata',x(i),'ydata',y(i)); % move the point using set
                                  % to change the cooridinates.
 M(i)=getframe(gcf);

end


for j=1:length(x)

 set(hLine2,'xdata',x(j),'ydata',y(j)); % move the point using set
                                  % to change the cooridinates.
 N(j)=getframe(gcf);

end



%% Play the movie back


% create figure and axes for playback
figure
hh=axes;
set(hh,'units','normalized','pos',[0 0 1 1]); 
axis off

movie(M)
movie(N)% play the movie created in the first part
```

The script works but it moves only one point and not the the points. Can somebody help me and say why only one point moves?

Kind Regards

Comment: Please explain what your problem is. It's great to post your code, but you should also explain exactly where you are struggling rather than expect people to analyse your code line by line looking for a problem

Comment: Sorry i pressed to fast on submitting. I hope you now understand it.

Answer (score 0):

A first guess is maybe you wanted this:

```
for ii=1:length(x)
   set(hLine,'xdata',x(ii),'ydata',y(ii)); 
   set(hLine2,'xdata',x(length(x) - ii + 1),'ydata',y(length(x) - ii + 1));                              
   M(i)=getframe(gcf);
end
.
.
.
movie(M)
```

Comment: Now it moves also only one point because the variable i is only in the for loop.

Comment: @skfjsdlfk Sorry the `j`s should be `i`s. Also a side note, `i` (and `j`) is a constant for sqrt(-1) in Matlab, so it's often recommended to not use it as a variable name in matlab

Comment: Ok tnx for the advise about the i and j. But i want that those 2 points move independently and they need even stop at specific points for a specific time :p

Comment: @skfjsdlfk so then you need to define that. I'll edit it to make them go in opposite directions (I hope) to give you a clue at how to mess around with them